# Send Data to display to another terminal opened by system(xterm) in C programming

Tags: c

I have open terminal to show output in c program by

```
system(xterm)
```

now i want to send more data results to that opened external terminal. 
i have seen **xterm -e** option, but i am not getting that. 
in my program , i have to processes concurrently working, one is sending message to another processes. and another is receiving responses. i want to show that on external terminal, every time it receive, i  want to show data on another terminal that is already opened.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pid_t pid;
int fds[2], in;
char f[PATH_MAX + 1];
//Creating new terminal and sending data through pipes
if(pipe(fds) == -1) {
    abort();
}
if(pid = fork() == 0){
close(fds[1]);
sprintf(f, "/dev/fd/%d", fds[0]);
execlp("xterm", "xterm","-e", "cat", f, (char *)NULL);
}
close(fds[0]);
sprintf(buf,"%s",name);
write(fds[1], buf, strlen(buf));
//Keep receiving the broadcast messages
while(1){
    ret = recv(clisockfd, buf, sizeof(buf) -1, 0);
    if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error receiving message");
            exit(1);
}
buf[ret] = '\0';
write(fds[1], buf, strlen(buf));
}
close(clisockfd);
```